# Set an image to no transparency, even though the background is transparent?

Tags: html, css

I know this will make some of your heads explode, but I'm building a website 1995-style. Tacky background images, flashing gifs, tabled layout, hit counter - everything. And none of it responsive or mobile friendly. And...I'm trying to do it with only tech available in 1995. Pure HTML, deprecated tags, and very little CSS. I'm doing this on purpose, as crazy as that sounds.

Anyway...my question. The easiest thing to do to understand is to visit the homepage of my site: thecreepingcrud.com (SFW)

You'll see the tabled layout. I have the opacity of the table set to 0.8. But you'll notice that the pic of the scary girl is also transparent at 0.8, and the tacky background image is showing through the image of the scary girl. I want to keep the table background at 0.8 opacity, but make the scary girl image not transparent at all. The tacky background image should show in the background of the table, but not in the pic of the scary girl.

I tend to get wordy. Sorry. Can this be done in pure HTML? CSS is ok if absolutely necessary, but inline CSS only. I'm trying to keep this site as primitive as possible.

I have attached the inline style opacity on every HTML tag I can think of - I've tried it on the table, table row, table cell, the image itself, I've wrapped the image in both a span and a div and tried to attach the inline opacity tag on those tags. Nothing seems to work.

Look at the code for the page. You'll see it's really simple 1995-era HTML. It's sloppy too!

Comment: "*I'm trying to do it with only tech available in 1995*" - then you shouldn't be using CSS (initially released in 1996, and `opacity` didn't show up until - I think - around 2011 or so. The only option back in '95 may have been .png images, but I don't think they were supported until 1997 or 1998. Also, you need to share a representative sample of your "*[mcve]*" code here in your question, posting a link is not sufficient.

Comment: Did you try `background-color: rgb(0 0 0/80%);`? you can remove opacity and set this background for your table. try this and let me know the result.

Comment: @Amirhoseinh73 unfortunately that is CSS which wasn't around in 1995- styling was done by tags and attributes.

Comment: This reference on png history implies you can't use them in a 1995 version - the first definition wasn't until late 1996 let alone the first implementation - see https://www.itpro.co.uk/web-browser/30247/what-is-a-png-file